# Determine whether or not the following series are convergent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sin(\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether or not the following series are convergent$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

How do I go about using the nth term test to prove this without the use of L'Hopital's?

Comment: What is the $n$th term test? The fact that convergence implies $a_n \to 0$? Either way, notice that $\sin x = x + O(x^3)$ as $x \to 0$, so $a_n = 1 + O(n^{-2})$.

Comment: Just to say: I don't think the argument via L'Hopital would be great.  After all, the relevant limit is needed in order to establish the derivative of $sin(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

Given series diverges, because
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin \frac{1}{n}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.
$$

Comment: How did you get nsin(1/n) to sinx/x?

Comment: @user323388 Define $x=\frac{1}{n}$.